# Understanding `%-14s%` and `%2s%` when formatting string literals

Tags: python

Hi I am quite new at python I just an explanation of what the `%-14s%` and `%2s%` does and if so, can you change it to something else or are those nr specific?

```
def __str__(self):

    return "%-14s"%self.Namn  + "%2s"%self.Spelade_matcher + "%2s"%self.Vinster + "%2s"%self.Oavgjorda +"%2s"%self.Förluster + "%3s"%self.Gjorda_mål +"%3s"%self.Insläppta_mål  + "%2s"%self.Poäng
```

Comment: Did you try printing it? It specifies justification with string formatting.

Comment: read [this](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: See [this page](https://pyformat.info/) for more information on string formatting.

Comment: Maybe This resource meets your needs. -> https://pyformat.info/

Comment: so how could I change this one to the new formating?

Comment: cause when I try the `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`pops up

Answer (score 3):

That is the old stlye string formatting of Python.
See it in details here: https://pyformat.info/

To be more specific about your question:
`"%-14s"` will pad your string to 14 characters and align your content to the left, for example `"%-14s" % ('blabla')` is gonna be: `'blabla        '`.

While `"%2s"` will pad your string to 2 characters and by default align your content to the right.